# How to show time duration on y-axis in high chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

here i want to show time duration on y-axis but not displaying, I have written following series of data.

```
series: [{
            name: 'Months',
            data: ["00:00:10", "00:42:10","01:00:00","21:00:10","05:10:10","12:00:10","05:00:10","02:00:10","00:50:10","00:40:10", "00:20:10", "10:10:10"]
        }]
```

Please check jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tank_hit/4usn4tp0/ i had tried but not displaying.

How to achieve this things ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate that strings in to numbers. In your case, it should be number of miliseconds. Then set `yAxis.type` to `"linear"` and see th result http://jsfiddle.net/4usn4tp0/3/

Code:

```
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        showFirstLabel: false,
        type: "datetime",
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                var ts = this.value,
                    hs = ts / (3600 * 1000),
                    ms = new Date(ts).getUTCMinutes();

                ms = ms < 10 ? '0' + ms : ms;
                hs = hs < 10 ? '0' + hs : hs;

                return hs + ":" + ms;
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Months',
        data: [ 10 * 60 * 1000, 42 * 60 * 1000, 60 * 60 * 1000]
    }]
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but how to show data into tooltip ?

Comment: now i pass   `data: [ 10 * 60 * 1000, 42 * 60 * 1000 , (21*60) * 60 * 1000]` at top of yaxis display `2. Jan` see result http://jsfiddle.net/tank_hit/4usn4tp0/5/

Comment: Right, you can not use built-in formatters for tooltip and labels. Create your own: [`tooltip.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) and [`yAxis.labels.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter)

Comment: one problem still arise, once i pass `21:00:00`as a  `(21*60*1000) ` to display label on yaxis is `2.Jan` instead of `21:00` check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tank_hit/4usn4tp0/5/

Comment: Yes, that's why I told you to use `yAxis.labels.formatter`. Also right now labels are rendered every 4th hour. So after 20:00, next label is 24:00 or next day ( there won't be 21:00).

Comment: yes exactly, i don't want next day label, continue to be 21:00,22:00,24:00,25:00,26:00 etc...... but how can i do ? please help if you having idea

Comment: Sure, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4usn4tp0/7/ - notus the same logic in tooltip.formatter.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a help

Comment: Hi Pawel Fus, can you tell me how can I convert `21:10:10` time duration into digit ?

Comment: Hi Pawel Fus, i got idea i have convert time into `milisecond` to get output check jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tank_hit/4usn4tp0/12/

Comment: Looks fine. Note your tooltip should use the same formatter, otherwise you will get wrong info, see last point: http://jsfiddle.net/4usn4tp0/14/

Comment: Hey Pawel Fus, I need one more help from your side, please can you give me your email address to describe easly.

Comment: Just create proper question on SO. Or send question directly to Highcharts [support](http://www.highcharts.com/support).